# String, byte[] and compression

Tags: java, compression

We can disassemble `String` to and from `byte[]` easily

```
        String s = "my string";
        byte[] b = s.getBytes();
        System.out.println(new String(b)); // my string
```

When compression is involved however there seem to be some issues. Suppose you have 2 methods, `compress` and `uncompress` (code below works fine)

```
public static byte[] compress(String data) 
             throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    byte[] input = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    Deflater df = new Deflater();
    df.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
    df.setInput(input);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length);
    df.finish();
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while (!df.finished()) {
        int count = df.deflate(buff);
        baos.write(buff, 0, count);
    }
    baos.close();
    byte[] output = baos.toByteArray();

    return output;
}

public static String uncompress(byte[] input) 
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException,
        DataFormatException {
    Inflater ifl = new Inflater();
    ifl.setInput(input);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length);
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while (!ifl.finished()) {
        int count = ifl.inflate(buff);
        baos.write(buff, 0, count);
    }
    baos.close();
    byte[] output = baos.toByteArray();

    return new String(output);
}
```

My Tests work as follows (works fine)

```
String text = "some text";
byte[] bytes = Compressor.compress(text);
assertEquals(Compressor.uncompress(bytes), text); // works
```

For no reason other then, why not, i'd like to modify the first method to return a `String` instead of the `byte[].`

So i `return new String(output)` from the `compress` method and modify my tests to:

```
String text = "some text";
String compressedText = Compressor.compress(text);
assertEquals(Compressor.uncompress(compressedText.getBytes), text); //fails
```

This test fails with `java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check`

**Why is that? What needs to be done to make it work?**

Comment: I would use a DeflatorOutputStream and an InflatorInputStream

Comment: To convert between strings and bytes, you should _really, really_ specify a specific encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String(byte[])` constructor is the problem. You cannot simply take arbitrary bytes, convert them to a string and then back to byte array. `String` class performs sophisticated encoding on this `byte` based on desired charset. If given byte sequence can't be represented e.g. in Unicode it will be discarded or converted to something else. The conversion from bytes to `String` and back to `bytes` is lossless only if these bytes really represented some `String` (in some encoding).

Here is a simplest example:

```
new String(new byte[]{-128}, "UTF-8").getBytes("UTF-8")
```

The above returns `-17, -65, -67` while `127` input returns the exact same output.

Comment: Can you provide an example of lossless conversion please? Also, in my example, bytes really do represent some String.

Comment: @Jam: what do you mean? I added an example where this conversion breaks. Lossless conversion would be [tag:base64] which can encode any byte array into a portable ASCII string.

Comment: @Jam in your example code `compress()` method returns compressed data as a String. Data after compression is clearly not a valid text.

Comment: @Alex: I've no idea where are these bytes coming from. But surely they represent some valid UTF-8 character.

Comment: Integer.toHexString(new String(new byte[]{-128}, "UTF-8").codePointAt(0)) = "fffd". Unicode replacement character = U+FFFD. So that's where the bytes are coming from :)

Answer (score 1):

It fails, because you just convert from bytes to string using the current encoding of your platform. So most bytes will be converted to their equivalent character codes but some might be replaced by other codes, depending on the current encoding. To see what happens to your bytes, just run:

```
byte[] b = new byte[256];
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    b[i] = (byte)i;
}
String s = new String(b);

for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + s.substring(i, i+1) + " " + (int)s.charAt(i));
}
```

As you can see, if you convert that back to bytes some codes fall all to the same value. And this sample does not handle encodings where a character is encoded with more than one code as in UTF-8.

In general one should avoid calling `String.getBytes()` and `new String(byte[])` without supplying an appropriate encoding parameter. And there is no one-to-one encoding where each byte becomes the corresponding character code unless you code your own.

If you really want to handle your compressed data as String, then use a base64 representation or a hex dump. But beware, the string representation needs twice as much memory, base64 adds a factor of 4/3, hex even a factor of 2. This might eat up the benefit of compression.